# Dart - Get command line arguments through console with .exe

Tags: flutter, dart

Is it possible for me to build a .exe file and than receive command line arguments using a console?

Example: `project.exe points.pts output.pts`, where .exe is the built dart code, points.pts is a list of points passed and used in the code, and output.pts is the output of the program.

In c this would be done simply by using `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`. I have found `import 'package:args/args.dart';` for arguments, but how can I combine in with a built .exe dart file?

I hope I explained my problem clearly.

Comment: read [A tour of the Dart language](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour)

Comment: Specifically: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#the-main-function

Comment: I know I can get command line arguments, my question is, is it possible to use them with a .exe file?